# Why vector in C++ doesn't utilize move semantics when its capacity grows?

Tags: c++, stdvector, move-semantics

Recently, when I am testing the implement of std::vector, I found that when the capacity of an vector grows, it uses copy construction to initialize the objects in the newly-allocated memory, rather than move construction.

In my point of view, when the capacity of an vector grows, the old objects in the old memory become useless. Therefore, I think they should be moved to the new memory, but not copied. If the objects are costly to copy but easy to move (e.g. std::string) , then the current implement of std::vector is rather slow!

Can somebody explain for me why vector in C++ doesn't utilize move semantics when its capacity grows? Thanks so much!

Here's my code for test. (Windows 64bit,-std=c++11)

```
// Testing the implement of C++ standard template library.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Custom object for test use.
struct object {
    void * ptr;
    size_t val;
    object() {std::cout << "Construction.\n";}
    object(object &&) {std::cout << "Move Construction.\n";}
    object(const object &) {std::cout << "Copy Construction.\n";}
    object &operator = (object &&) {
        std::cout << "Move Assignment.\n";
        return *this;
    }
    object &operator = (const object &) {
        std::cout << "Copy Assignment.\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

inline void printline() {std::cout << "----------------------\n";}

signed main() {
    std::vector <object> test(2); // size = capacity = 2
    printline();
    test.resize(3); // now the capacity must grow
    printline();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Construction.
Construction.
----------------------
Construction.
Copy Construction.
Copy Construction.
----------------------
```

What I think it should output:

```
Construction.
Construction.
----------------------
Construction.
Move Construction.
Move Construction.
----------------------
```

Comment: You need to make your move ctor noexcept, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Notes)

Comment: @RoQuOTriX A move is possible, and will happen if the move constructor is `noexcept`. Remember that moving is a form of copying that modifies the original object.

Comment: Micronag: you almost never want to use the `stl` tag `std::vector`. Most of the the Standard Template Library (STL) heavily influenced the design of the C++ Standard Library when C++ was standardized back in 1998. Almost no one uses es the STL today.

Comment: Demo when you add noexcept to move constructor : https://onlinegdb.com/A3rybW-Ia