# why is copy constructor called for every element of vector when i use push_back?

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor, move-constructor

i'm working on this exercise where i implement a class that holds a dynamically allocated built-in array (int*). i'm trying to implement the big 5 and i think it's working (it compiles and runs, anyway) but every time i add a new element to the vector containing objects of my class type (see main), it seems to call the copy constructor on all elements in the vector! (see the output below).

is this normal behavior for c++ vectors, or am i doing something wrong? thanks

```
class LargeTypeRaw
{
public:

     LargeTypeRaw(size_t initialSize = 10)
        : data{ new int[size] }, size{ initialSize }
     {
         std::cout << "normal constructor called" << std::endl;        
     }

     LargeTypeRaw(const LargeTypeRaw& other)
         : size{ other.size }, data{ new int[other.size]}
     {
         std::copy(other.data, other.data + other.size, data); 
         std::cout << "copy constructor called" << std::endl; 
     }

     LargeTypeRaw(LargeTypeRaw&& other)
         : size{ other.size }, data{ other.data }
     {
         std::cout << "move constructor called" << std::endl; 
         other.data = nullptr;
     }

     LargeTypeRaw& operator=(const LargeTypeRaw& other)
     {
         std::cout << "copy assignment operator called" << std::endl; 

         if (&other != this)
         {
             
             delete[] data;
             data = new int[other.size]; 
             std::copy(other.data, other.data+other.size, data); 
         }

         return *this; 
     }

     LargeTypeRaw& operator=(LargeTypeRaw&& other)
     {
         std::cout << "move assignment operator called" << std::endl; 

         if (&other != this)
         {
             delete[] data;
             data = other.data; 
             other.data = nullptr; 
         }

         return *this;   
     }
 
    ~LargeTypeRaw()
    {
        std::cout << "destructor called " << std::endl; 
        delete [] data;
    }

    size_t getSize() const
    {
        return size; 
    }

    bool operator<(const LargeTypeRaw& rhs) const
    {
        return size < rhs.size; 
    }


private:
    int* data;
    size_t size; 
};




int main()
{
    
    //example using LargeTypes that hold int
    std::vector<LargeTypeRaw> vec{};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        size_t size = rand() % 10;
        std::cout << "initializing another object " << std::endl;
        LargeTypeRaw lt{ size }; 
        std::cout << "adding the new object to the vector " << std::endl; 
        vec.push_back(lt);
    }

    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Because you are adding a copy of the thing you push

Comment: Not sure if I found the _most_ appropriate dupe, but the short answer is "Yes, this is normal behavior for C++ vectors, they copy elements when they need to resize to keep all stored objects in a contiguous region of memory"

Comment: i see, thanks. so i guess (if i know the final size) i should just initialize the vector with that capacity to start?

Comment: Sidenote: You (try to) initialize the members in the wrong order here: `LargeTypeRaw(size_t initialSize = 10) : data{new int[size]}, size{initialSize}`.  Which causes UB in your program

Comment: Some `noexcept` are missing to have **move** instead of **copy**.[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j8sY7zcan)

Comment: This is surpisingly similar to [this today's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75142681/2752075).

Comment: Regarding my previous comment: You use `size` in `new int[size]` when it's uninitialized.